# populate pandas dataframe using csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files:

File1: An empty dataframe with only a header. (the data frame I wish to populate)

```
item A B C D E F G H
```

File2: A CSV file with space-delimited elements with uneven column numbers

```
item1 A B D F 
item2 A B C D E
item3 A H I 
item4 C D E F G
item5 K L
```

The output I expect is the following:

```
item |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H
----------------------
item1 A B   D   F
item2 A B C D E
item3 A             H
item4     C D E F G
```

The code is below and partially working:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('to_map.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

with open('to_search.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        elements = line.strip().split(" ")
        first_element = elements[0]

        row = {}  # Create an empty dictionary for each row
        for element in elements:
            row[element] = first_element
            if element in df.columns:
                row[element] = element  # Match found, update to corresponding column
            else:
                row[element] = pd.NA  # Match not found, assign NA

        # Append the row to the DataFrame
        df = df._append(row, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
item    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H item1 item2 item3    I item4  \
0  NaN    A    B  NaN    D  NaN    F  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   
1  NaN    A    B    C    D    E  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   
2  NaN    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    H   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   
3  NaN  NaN  NaN    C    D    E    F    G  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   

  item5    K    L  
0   NaN  NaN  NaN  
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

As you can see, the item(1..n), K, L, though not in column header, it still written as separate column and filled with NaNs. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much easier:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('File1.tsv', header=0, sep=' ')
df2 = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', header=0, sep=' ')
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1])
```

Comment: Hello, the problem with CSV file is that the column numbers of each line are uneven. Importing as dataframe is difficult. Gives error "expected x columns but got y columns"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# file2
column_names = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=" ").columns

# file1
data = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=" ", names=column_names)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
    item  A    B    C    D    E    F    G
0  item1  A    B    C    D    E    F    G
1  item2  A    B    C    D    E  NaN  NaN
2  item3  A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  item4  C    D    E    F    G  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this concatenates two tables, but does not put the appropriate row values matching with the column name. Ideally row 3 should have been "item 4 NaN NaN C D E F G"

Answer (score 0):

Your files are space separated. So I added some spaces on the file1.csv so that it can be loaded in their right column position.

I think the following can be done:

```py
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',sep=' ', header=None)
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep=' ')

new_cols = dict(zip(file1.columns,file2.columns))
populated_df=file1.rename(columns=new_cols)

# to see the new populated dataframe on python
populated_df
```

| item | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| item2 | A | B | C | D | E | NaN | NaN |
| item3 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| item4 | NaN | NaN | C | D | E | F | G |

```py
# to export to a csv file
populated_df.to_csv('populated_file.csv',index=False,header=True)
# Or if you want uncomment this (and comment the previous line) to just override file1 so that it is "populated"
# populated_df.to_csv('file1.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

The populated_file.csv is like the following when loaded on spreadsheets:

[image: Populated csv loaded on LibreOFfice]

Comment: In my original file, the first line in item1 does not have all the elements. Hence the pd.read_csv throws the following error: ~~ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 3, saw 14~~

Comment: I modified the read method in file2 with file2 = pd.read_csv('to_search.txt', sep=' ', names=range(len(file1))). But still it produced 'Empty Dataframe'

Comment: You will have to add the necessary spaces to the first line. Idk if there exists another way.. The first barrier is that your file is not comma separated value but space separated.. If your file has a greater number of rows, it will be hard to add the necessary spaces manually.

Comment: Maybe there could be a first script for uniforming the files with commas and blank spaces where there is no data. After that, a simple concatenation could be done.